Mongodb 7 cluster profiling status
In a percona mongodb 7 cluster i want to set the profile level to one and logs only operation that are slower than 250 ms.
To do so i run the following command:
>db.setProfilingLevel(1, 250)
and then run:
>db.getProfilingStatus()
Getting this result:
{
  was: 1,
  slowms: 250,
  ratelimit: 100,
  sampleRate: 1,
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1717663934, i: 13114 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("000000000000000000000")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1717663934, i: 13114 })
}

If i connect to the cluster using the mongodb compass client I can still see much slower operations:

I thought to see only operations slower that 250 ms, am I missing something?
How much can the profiling settings impact the database performances for level 1 and 2?
I tried to increase the slow operations threshold to 250ms and I was expecting to not see slower operations (< 250).
But I can still see slower operation showed on compass cliente performances tab as showed in the attched image.

The documentation suggests that the info in Compass is populated by different means (eg the mongostat command) rather than from profiling itself. In other words, profiling should not influence what shows up in that tab in Compass which matches the behavior that you've observed
